# How can I pass a non-constant int as a template argument?

Tags: c++, templates, matrix, non-type-template-parameter

I wonder how can I create a matrix whose size is given from command line. It can be done trivially if it is a non template matrix class. But what if the matrix class is a template class (like in Eigen), how can I do to create a matrix whose size is given from command line?

```cpp
template<int _row, int _col>
class Matrix{
...
};

int main{
    // assign rows and cols dynamically
    int row;
    int col;
    std::cin >> row >> col;

    // Some procedures

    Matrix<row, col> m;
    return 0;
}
```

Edit:

Thanks @hyde and @marcinj. I thought there are some magic mechanism behind Eigen's implementation. By looking into the Eigen's code again, I think they use template arguments `int _Cols, int _Rows` only for small matrix and define `Dynamic` to be some constants like -1 and handle it on runtime.

Comment: Templates expand to code *at compile time*. So just pass them as normal constructor arguments, and handle them at runtime.

Comment: But in Eigen matrix is  "template<typename _Scalar, int _Rows, int _Cols, int _Options, int _MaxRows, int _MaxCols> class Matrix''. how can they manage to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is you cannot, templates are instantiated at compile time so row and col would have to be known at compile time too.

You will have to implement a non templated Matrix class to achive what you want. Pass row/col to constructor and allow class to dynamically allocate memory for the matrix.

[edit]

If you want to implement your Matrix in similar way as in Eigen, you will have too look into their implementation. In here:

https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Matrix.html

you can see that their templated Matrix accepts row and col as template parameter, when parameter is of some specified value `Dynamic` (this might be some very large value like `std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max()`), then Matrix uses matrix sizes as provided in constructor parameters.

If code for dynamic template matrix should be significantly different then you could provide specialization for it.

Comment: But in Eigen matrix is "template<typename _Scalar, int _Rows, int _Cols, int _Options, int _MaxRows, int _MaxCols> class Matrix''. how can they manage to do it?

Comment: read docs : https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Matrix.html. In template parameters it is stated `_Rows Number of rows, or Dynamic`, so for dynamic matrix you should provide `Dynamic` keyword. Then row/col is probably provided in constructor. I have not worked with Eigen so that is as far as I can help here.

Comment: @TalhaIrfan dynamic allocation is often done with pointers, so yes.