# Repeat with variable min/max using boost.xpressive

Tags: c++, templates, boost-xpressive

I'm using boost.xpressive static templates to construct regular expressions that are dynamically concatenated into a final expression.

The dynamic version has a variable-width repeat, but I do need to use the static constructions due to operating in int vectors.

I do need to create `repeat<N,M>` where `N` and `M` are not constants.

How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, C++ only permits you to pass template arguments known at compile time   (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37343291/pass-non-constant-integer-to-template-arguments-from-in-c)) aka [constant expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression).

In this case, it means that the values entered into `repeat<N, M>` must be literals or constant expressions, so you can't enter just any `int` of you program.

Its hard to give more concrete advice without seeing any code, but it seems that you are trying to create a regexp which matches for example `n` repetitions of some group / literal, where `n` is not yet known at compile time (i.e., depending on some input to your program).

This seems like a strange use case, after all, regular expressions are generally compile time constants (which is the reason for boost-xpressive to exist).

I would recommend using dynamic (ordinary) regular expressions instead. Regular expressions are *compiled* (preprocessed to speed up matching in the implementation of the regular expression engine) anyways.

Generally a regular expression is generated once and then used many times to match different strings. Thus, the preprocessing step is generally negligible in terms of performance.

**Edit**

Per your request, here is a *dynamic* version, contained in a `main`, which 
matches based on parameters:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <boost/xpressive/xpressive.hpp>

using namespace boost::xpressive;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  smatch what;

  int min_match = std::stoi(argv[1]);
  int max_match = std::stoi(argv[2]);

  std::ostringstream expr_buf;

  expr_buf << "a{" << min_match
           << ","
           << max_match
           << "}"
           << "b";

  sregex rex = sregex::compile(expr_buf.str());

  std::string value = argv[3];

  if(regex_match(value, what, rex))
  {
    std::cout << "There was a complete match" << std::endl;
  }
  else
  {
    std::cout << "There was no complete match" << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

For example:

`./main 1 3 "aaab" -> "There was a complete match"`

`./main 1 3 "cab" -> "There was no complete match"`

`./main 4 5 "aaab" -> "There was no complete match"`

Comment: Every thing you said I know, sorry. The thing is, boost-xpressive has dynamic support for {N,M} when compiling a string, but does not have it in the lower-level static way. You migh say "it's static", but ranges supports dynamic a-b parameters. Looks like a design problem in boost-xpressive.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by ranges (the C++20 ones?), but I guarantee you that the same thing will happen: If there is some `range_of_ints_between<a, b>` function / class, then `a` and `b` have to constant expressions as well, that is what the standard says. If there is some function `get_range(int a, int b)`, then they don't. I don't think that is a design problem in boost-xpressive. The C++ language does not permit dynamic (i.e. not constant expression) values in template arguments.

Comment: You are replying my questions thinking on C++, but my question is about boost.xpressive. I talked about regex ranges.